# Панель действий Android

Tags: android, actionbar

Итак, я - новичок, изучаю по книжке программирование на Android и возникла проблема с панелью действий. Я не могу добавить туда ни одной кнопки (могу только при нажатии на троеточие, где выплывает список с моими `item`). Как я понял, чтобы добавить кнопку в панель нужно создать папку `menu` в которой создать XML файл допустим `menu_main`, написать нужный код и добавить `item`, в котором указать `showAsAction`, `id` и т.д. Далее в активности создать `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, через инфлатер привязать меню и должно вроде как всё получится. Я приложу свой код:

Меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/action_create_order"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_create_black"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Активность:

```
package com.hfad.bitsandpizzas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_create_order:
            // Действие
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // Действие
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Вот, что выводит эмулятор, кстати, minSDK = 17, если это имеет значение. На моём Galaxy S4 этого троеточия нет и в помине, за нее отвечает кнопка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не очень ясна проблема - у вас не работает на устройстве, эмуляторе или в предпросмоторщике студии? И что именно не работает?

Comment: Может попробуйте не `Activity`, а `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нигде. Мне надо, чтобы на панели появилась кнопочка с иконкой, а в итоге `item` появляется в списке при нажатии на троеточие

Comment: @Иван, попробуйте AppCompatActivity вместо Activity. и не проверяйте работоспособность в предпросмотрорщике.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб изменил, поменял импорты, теперь выдает ошибку `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity`
Как я понял, ошибка связана с темами, я использую (по книге) 2 темы:
Одна в папке values `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">`
Вторая в папке values-v21
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">`
А проверяю я на своем телефоне и эмуляторе

Comment: Смените родительскую тему на `Theme.AppCompat`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо сменить супер класс активити на `AppCompatActivity` и сменить родительскую тему в стилях на `Theme.AppCompat`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Comment: пробовал, ничего толкового из этого не вышло. Проблема была классе наследнике и теме