# Не находит тему Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-style

Всем привет! Хочу использовать в приложении тему Theme.AppCompat для корректного отображения пиктограм на панели действий. Но не получается, ошибка:

Error:(360) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.AppCompat'.

C dependencies вроде бы все нормально:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
```

Но в Андроид Студио все горит красным
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом можно открыть редактор тем, посмотреть как эта тема выглядит, но при сборке почему-то не находится.

P.S. Надобность возникла по той же причине, что и у топикстратера  [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531906/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-android) темы, но решение с изменением темы и родителя не проходит.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `android:`

Comment: AppCompat подключаемая библиотека, ее ресурсы не входят в пространство имен `android:`

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
android:Theme.AppCompat
```

На

```
@style/Theme.AppCompat
```

Также не забудьте унаследовать свои классы не от `Activity`, а от `AppCompatActivity`, тоесть

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity
```